# Convert TEXT To PDF Using PDFSharp

Tags: converters, pdfsharp

I want to convert a text file to PDF using PDFsharp. What should be the approach? Is it even possible? I'm developing a web application using C#.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach would be to check the samples for PDFsharp and MigraDoc and then decide which tool to use.

I would guess that MigraDoc will be the better choice if the text may require more than just one page.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx

Answer (score 5):

I wrote down a code for this purpose.

Initially, i used pdfsharp dll for this, but this did not work for me since pdfsharp can not sense page breaks, when i wrote my code, i saw that only the ones which fit in the first page is printed.

Then i learnt that Migradoc does sense page breaks and add new pages if needed automatically.

Here is my method with two parameters:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
using MigraDoc.Rendering;
using System.IO;



  void CreatePDFFileFromTxtFile(string textfilefullpath, string pdfsavefullpath)
            {
                //first read text to end add to a string list.
                List<string> textFileLines = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textfilefullpath))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        textFileLines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }

                Document doc = new Document();
                Section section = doc.AddSection();

                //just font arrangements as you wish
                MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 15);
                font.Bold = true;

                //add each line to pdf 
                foreach (string line in textFileLines)
                {
                    Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
                    paragraph.AddFormattedText(line,font);

                }


                //save pdf document
                PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();
                renderer.Document = doc;
                renderer.RenderDocument();
                renderer.Save(pdfsavefullpath);
            }
```

And call this method with input text full path and output pdf file full path to create.

This works.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to mix PDFsharp and MigraDoc, my solution required me to pull out the text and reopen a fresh stream. Perhaps not the best solution if you have a local path save option, but if you are creating an API like I am, stream is probably your best option, and this worked for me. Note, I am appending to an existing PDFsharp PdfDocument in the middle of a PDF merge document process.

```
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
using MigraDoc.Rendering;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

...

var txt = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(attachStream))
{
    // read txt
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        txt.Add(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
    }
}

// prep doc
var doc = new Document();
var sec = doc.AddSection();
var font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
foreach (var line in txt)
{
    var par = sec.AddParagraph();
    par.AddFormattedText(line, font);
}

// render
using (var renderDoc = new PdfDocument())
{
    var render = new PdfDocumentRenderer
    {
        Document = doc,
        PdfDocument = renderDoc
    };
    render.RenderDocument();

    // append
    using (Stream appendStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        renderDoc.Save(appendStream);
        using (var inputDoc = PdfReader.Open(appendStream,
            PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
        {
            foreach (var page in inputDoc.Pages)
            {
                outputDoc.Pages.Add(page);
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```