# Use PDFsharp-wpf to convert txt files to pdf in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, txt

I am having issues converting my files to pdf. I am completely new to C# (coming from java) and I am trying to build an application that first prints out a log into a text file then converts it to a PDF. If you know a good resource or example please point me in the right direction without judgement. Thank you!

```
createPDF(myFileString);
void createPDF(string txtFile)
{
    string line = null;
    System.IO.TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(myFileString);
    int yPoint = 0;

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
    pdf.Info.Title = "TXT to PDF";
    PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
    XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);

    while (true)
    {
        line = readFile.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
        {
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While
        }
        else
        {
            yPoint = yPoint + 40;
        }
    }

    string pdfFilename = "txttopdf.pdf";
    pdf.Save(pdfFilename);
    readFile.Close();
    readFile = null;
    Process.Start(pdfFilename);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Pdfsharp's website, specifically their [wiki](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/)? They have code samples very similar to what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I thought it was only MigraDoc documentation. I will take another look. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013859/convert-text-to-pdf-using-pdfsharp